# Typo3 - WFQBE granular permissions for FE

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-4.5

We have a few pages that do not exist in the Typo3 BE, and we are trying to set granular permissions to allow certain people access to make changes. Without being able to navigate via the BE to apply the permissions.  These pages are created by WFQBE queries, so managing it looks difficult.

Presently, we can just apply the permissions to all the users and can not specify user groups.

Would this require a custom extension? To manage user permissions over this other areas?